# Multi select in RecyclerView selects views which have not been selected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a multiselect feature in my app. This works fine but the problem appears when I select a card on the app and scroll down the `RecyclerView`, the 4th item on the list is already selected. This is how my onBindViewHolder looks like:

```
holder.rvPictureContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        model.setSelected(!model.getSelected());
        holder.rvPictureContainer.setCardBackgroundColor(model.getSelected() ? ContextCompat.getColor(ctx, R.color.colorAccent) : Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```

This is my model:

```
public class PictureModel {
private String imgURL, imgTitle, imgAuthor;
private Boolean isSelected = false;

public PictureModel(String imgURL, String imgTitle, String imgAuthor) {
    this.imgURL = imgURL;
    this.imgTitle = imgTitle;
    this.imgAuthor = imgAuthor;
}

public String getImgURL() {
    return imgURL;
}

public String getImgTitle() {
    return imgTitle;
}

public String getImgAuthor() {
    return imgAuthor;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    isSelected = selected;
}

public Boolean getSelected() {
    return isSelected;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to notify which element has been changed

Comment: Post the whole code from Adapter class please. I think I'll know how to help you when I see it.

Comment: Why don't you use drawable selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since recycler view reuses cells, you need to clear the state of the cell it's being reused. You can do that by setting the current state of the cell on `onBindViewHolder`. Ex.:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(YourViewHolder holder, int position, List<Object> payloads) {
    YourModel model = items[position]
    holder.setup(model)
}
```

Inside the `setup`, make sure to set the proper state for that cell.

In your case, that means setting the correct selected state.

I hope this helps.